Neomodel library, Check if node relationship is connected to any other node
I feel like the NeoModel library is not well-documented or optimized for many cases.
I have a neomodel StructuredNode
class Guest(User):
    x_account = RelationshipTo('x', 'Has_x_account', cardinality=One)
    y_account = RelationshipTo('y', 'Has_y_account', cardinality=One)

I want when to retrieve all nodes and loop on each user to check if x_account relationship is connected or not.
guests = Guest.nodes.all()

Using guests[0].x_account will show me that there is a relationship but I can't tell if its connected to another node.
using guests[0].x_account.is_connected(node) requires to know the other node in advance.
The only way I found is the following but I had to handle the exception.
try:
    guests[0].x_account .single()  
    has_x_account = True
except exceptions.CardinalityViolation:
    has_x_account = False

I can't make it. Any idea?
